# 時系列のデータを折れ線グラフにし、グラフの平らな部分を検出したい

Tags: r

時系列のデータを折れ線グラフにするスクリプトは、下記のように書きました。

```
a <- read.table("Sequence2.csv",sep=",", header=T)
names(a) <- c("NO","Time","SequenceNO")
plot( a[,c("TIME")],a[,c("SequenceNO")],type="l")
```

[image: 時系列変動]

グラフはこのようになったのですが、グラフの傾きが平らな部分を検出するにはどうすればいいでしょうか。

元のデータ：testfile.csv

```
    TIME    SequenceNO
1   0.000023    7
2   0.003774    1455
3   0.004244    2903
4   0.004645    4351
5   0.004667    5799
6   0.0047      7247
7   0.00472     8695
8   0.004818    13039
9   0.004839    18831
10  0.004936    20279
11  0.011538    27519
12  0.029395    34759
13  0.029433    49239
14  0.035552    60823
15  0.039416    60823
16  0.040157    60823
17  0.042644    60823
18  0.049411    60825
19  0.050914    60826
20  0.05136     76751
21  0.059166    101367
22  0.060155    120191
23  0.072393    141911
24  0.095405    152047
25  0.095636    191143
26  0.096089    211415
27  0.11215 262095
28  0.11589 276575
```

Comment: `Sequence2.csv` と `testfile.csv` は別のファイルですか？ `testfile.csv` は CSV には見えませんが…

Comment: 期待される出力フォーマットも質問文に含んでいただけると、解答しやすい気がします。

Comment: >>heliac2001さま
回答に記載いただいたのが、正しいファイルです。申し訳ございません。

>>3100さま

ありがとうございます。ご指摘の点も含めて、質問の書き方を改善しようと思っております。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「グラフの傾きが平らな部分」というのはまぁ、`df(x)/dx ≒ 0` ということなのでしょう、きっと。  
まずは、以下の関数を定義します。R に詳しければ `apply() family` を使って簡潔に定義できたのでしょうけれど、そうではないので `for loop` を使っています。

```
myfunc <- function (df, xn, yn) {
  x <- df[[xn]]
  y <- df[[yn]]
  if ( is.null(x) || is.null(y) ) {
    return(invisible(FALSE))
  }
  st <- -1
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    if ( i < nrow(df) &&
         abs(y[i+1] - y[i]) < (y[i] * 0.001) ) {
      if ( st < 0 ) {
        st <- x[i]
      }
    } else if ( st > 0 ) {
      cat(sprintf("%f - %f\n", st, x[i]))
      st <- -1
    }
  }
  invisible(TRUE)
}
```

入力データ `testfile.csv` を以下だと仮定します(長いので一部省略しています)。質問欄にある `testfile.csv` はなぜか CSV 形式ではないですね。。。

```
NO,Time,SequenceNO
1,0.000023,1455
2,0.003774,1455
3,0.004244,10
      :
14,0.035552,60823
15,0.039416,60823
16,0.040157,60823
17,0.042644,60823
18,0.049411,60825
19,0.050914,60826
20,0.05136,76751
      :
26,0.096089,262095
27,0.11215,262095
28,0.11589,262095
```

以下を実行します。

```
> a <- read.table("testfile.csv", sep=",", header=T)
> myfunc(a, "Time", "SequenceNO")
0.000023 - 0.003774
0.035552 - 0.050914
0.096089 - 0.115890
```

判定結果を `cat()` で stdout に出力していますが、vector などにして return する方が良いかもしれません。